# SQL запрос в Modx

Tags: modx, sql

Всем привет. Eсть такой запрос в БД modx он выбирает коментарии и имя человека который его оставил.

```
SELECT modx_jot_content.id, modx_jot_content.content, modx_jot_fields.content AS guestname 
FROM `modx_jot_content` INNER JOIN `modx_jot_fields` ON modx_jot_content.uparent = modx_jot_fields.id 
WHERE (modx_jot_content.uparent = 16) AND (modx_jot_fields.label=`name`)";
```

При его выполнении возникает такая ошибка:

MODx encountered the following error while attempting to parse the requested resource:
« Execution of a query to the database failed - Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause' »

SQL: SELECT modx_jot_content.id, modx_jot_content.content, modx_jot_fields.content AS guestname FROM `modx_jot_content` INNER JOIN `modx_jot_fields` ON modx_jot_content.uparent = modx_jot_fields.id WHERE (modx_jot_content.uparent = 16) AND (modx_jot_fields.label=`name`)

Если я правильно понял, то последний name принимает за столбец. 
Помогите правильно составить запрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Косые кавычки замените на прямые, если это не столбец, а строковая константа:

```
AND (modx_jot_fields.label='name')
```